# How to correctly integrate to get the error function

Tags: integration, error-function

I have the given [integral formula](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi3useqqL74AhVT4oUKHbGWCoYQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocplayer.net%2F90216448-Math-342-partial-differential-equations-viktor-grigoryan.html&usg=AOvVaw1B4HgydC-oagG7qdRSIBdv) for the diffusion equation on an infinite rod:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi\alpha t}}\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-y)^2/4\alpha t}-e^{-(x+y)^2/4\alpha t}\phi(y)dy
\end{equation}

From the given PDE

$u_t=\frac{1}{4}u_{xx}, \\
 \ u_x(0,t)=0, \\
 u(x,0)=\begin{cases}6 , 0<x<3\\
 0, x>3
\end{cases}$

I have that $\phi(y)=6$ and $\alpha=1/4 $ and inserting into the formula for $u(x,t)$ I get the integral:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{6}{\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-y)^2/t}-e^{-(x+y)^2/t}dy
\end{equation}

I want to solve this so I set  $u=\frac{(x-y)}{\sqrt{t}}\  and\  v=\frac{(x+y)}{\sqrt{t}}$ and get:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=-\frac{6}{\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_{\frac{-x}{\sqrt{t}}}^\infty e^{-(u)^2}du-\frac{6}{\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_{\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}}^\infty e^{-(v)^2}dv
\end{equation}

At this stage I see from [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cfrac%7B6%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B%5Cpi%20t%7D%7D%5Cint_%7B-x%2Fsqrt%28t%29%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20e%5E%7B-%28u%29%5E2%7Ddu-%5Cfrac%7B6%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B%5Cpi%20t%7D%7D%5Cint_%7Bx%2Fsqrt%28t%29%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20e%5E%7B-%28v%29%5E2%7D)  this yields:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=-\frac{3\operatorname{erf} \bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}} \bigg)+1}{\sqrt{t}}-\frac{2\operatorname{erfc}\bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}} \bigg)}{\sqrt{t}}
\end{equation}

But how is this calculated step by step? I can't find any sources online that describe this.

**Suggestion**

I tried converting it to radial coordinates, and using the fact that $\int e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\int\int e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy}=\sqrt{\int_0^{2\pi}\int e^{-r^2}rdrd\phi}$.

This approach on the first of the two integrals above gives:

$\int_{\frac{-x}{\sqrt{t}}}^\infty e^{-u^2}du$

\begin{equation}
\bigg(\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{-rcos\phi}{\sqrt{t}}}^\infty e^{-r^2}rdrd\phi\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}

For simplicity we consider:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{-rcos\phi}{\sqrt{t}}}^\infty e^{-r^2}rdrd\phi
\end{equation}

We now  substitute $w=r^2$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{-rcos\phi}{\sqrt{t}}}^\infty e^{-w}dw
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\bigg[e^{-w}\bigg]_{\frac{-rcos\phi}{\sqrt{t}}}^{\infty}d\phi
\end{equation}

Here,

\begin{equation}
\bigg[e^{-w}\bigg]_{\frac{-rcos\phi}{\sqrt{t}}}^{\infty}=e^{\frac{-r^2cos^2\phi}{t}}+1
\end{equation}

So we'd get:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\frac{-r^2cos^2\phi}{t}}+1
 d\phi
\end{equation}

rewriting to:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{-r^2}{t}}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\frac{1}{2}(1+cos2\phi)}+1
 d\phi
\end{equation}

and further to

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{-r^2}{t}}e^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\frac{1}{2}cos2\phi}+1  d\phi
\end{equation}

So the challenge is to solve without Wolfram alpha:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\frac{1}{2}cos2\phi} d\phi
\end{equation}

This integral gives the Bessel function of the first kind. Any ideas how that comes about?

Thanks

Comment: It's kinda the definition https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_0%5Ea+e%5Ev%5E2+dv

Comment: The error function is a non-elementary function, which is defined to send $z$ to $2\pi^{1/2}$ times the integral of $\exp(-x^2)$ from 0 to $z$, so the result holds by definition

Comment: those two integrals are the same by the way and it can be factored out

Comment: yeah after you edited it...

Answer (score 2):

The [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) is defined as
$$
\operatorname{erf} z = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^z e^{-t^2}\,dt
$$
The reason to define it like this is because this integral cannot be reduced to simpler functions.